# Horizontal Layout only sharing space equally between two widgets

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm building out my first GUI which goes deeper than a yes no button.  I've been struggling with this problem longer than its worth, since its probably simple.

I have the following layout in designer:

[image: current design]

While I have the vertical spacing as desired, I want the QOpenGLWidget to take up most of the horizontal space.  I cannot get the left layout to stop expanding when I expand the size of the window.  I would assume I could set the layout to a fixed width, but that does not seem possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the stretch factor in the layout, for this click on QHBoxLayout and change for the `layoutStretch` property from `0, 0` to `0, 1`.

[image]

Comment: The layoutStretch property has an array of 7 0s, as such: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0].  What do these values indicate about the layout?  Switching any of these single 0s to a 1 does not solve the issue I am facing.

Comment: @WhisperingShiba The number of elements depends on how many items are associated with the layout, so if you want more help provide a [mre]: share the content of the .ui.

Comment: @WhisperingShiba Note: You must first click on the QHBoxLayout, I think you have clicked on the QVBoxLayout which seems to have 7 items.